# Elastic Beanstalk in a Private VPC with EB CLI

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I would like to use Elastic Beanstalk in a private VPC.

Since there is no internet gateway in the VPC, the default internet facing load balancer creation fails.

Is there a way to create a Elastic Beanstalk Environment using the EB CLI? Is it possible to change the visibility of the created Load Balancer? (Internal facing LB should be working just fine in my private VPC.)

Is this possible via the command line options or I need to use [Advanced environment customization with configuration files (.ebextensions)](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/ebextensions.html)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The load balancer can be changed to be internally facing, by [using advanced environment configuration with configuration files (.ebextensions)](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/ebextensions.html)

The [aws:ec2:vpc namespace](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/command-options-general.html#command-options-general-ec2vpc) has a configuration setting for the ELBScheme.

According to this, you need create (if it is not already existing) a `.config` file in the `.ebextensions` subfolder and add the following configuration:

```
option_settings:
  aws:ec2:vpc:
    ELBScheme: internal
```

After changing the ELBScheme from the default (public) value, Beanstalk is not going to assign an Elastic IP anymore (which is causing problems in a private VPC).

When creating the Beanstalk environment using the eb cli, please make sure to specify the VPC id of the private VPC, by passing the --vpc.id argument all the other relevant settings, like subnet IDs to be used.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a [bastion server](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/vpc-bastion-host.html), a linux host in a public subnet, and use `eb ssh` to connect to your hosts. I have not tried creating a environment using CLI yet though.

Example OpenSSH config file:

```sh
Host 10.0.*
  User ec2-user
  ProxyCommand  ssh.exe -q -W %h:%p production

Host production
  Hostname {{HOSTNAME_BASION}}
  User ec2-user
```

Comment: This could work, if we had an internet gateway in the VPC, but in this case it is a private VPC without an internet gateway. There is no public subnet in the VPC.